# Почему так сильно тормозит проект на nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть проект: 188.225.26.136

Не могу разобраться почему такие сильные лаги, особенно в браузере сафари
Изображения максимально сжаты вместе с видео, следил за утечкой памяти, т.к использую TweenMax, но всё равно без результатов

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда стоит обратить внимание. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: В браузере Firefox не видно никаких лагов, всё шустренько

Comment: В safari уж сильно подтормаживает(

Comment: Со старту могу сказать, что то с кросбраузерностью